# How update row in table with array

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am having trouble dealing with the following:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {  
    values.put("id", i);
    DB.update("book", values, "_id between 1 and 100", null);
}
```

I am very sorry this is my code :

```
for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
values.put("id", strArray[i]);
DB.update("book", values, "_id between 1 and 100", null);
}
```

I want to update the column id with strArray in other words I want add all strArray in column id  where _id between 1 to 100
again so sorry

the result in table :

[image]

Can someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code updates in every iteration of the `for` loop all the rows of the table with `_id`s 1 up to 100.
 Each iteration uses the value of the variable `i` to update the column `id` of all these rows and what you see is the final result with the final value of `i` which is `100`.
If what you want is to update the column `id` with the value `x` in the row with `_id = x` then change to this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {  
    values.put("id", i);
    DB.update("book", values, "_id = " + i, null);
}
```

or better with a placeholder:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {  
    values.put("id", i);
    DB.update("book", values, "_id = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(i)});
}
```

or with a single statement:

```
DB.execSQL("UPDATE book SET id = _id WHERE _id BETWEEN 1 AND 100");
```

Comment: Thanks to your replay.

Comment: Plaease can any one help me Please Read My post Again

Comment: This code answers the question as you originally posted it. If you have a new requirement, instead of changing the question and invalidating the answer that you already got, you should post a new question.